# Can't communicate using PuTTY, but can with Termite

Tags: putty, serial, rs232

I'm trying to establish a serial connection to a peripheral from my PC's RS-232 port. Pretty simple stuff, and I've had not trouble doing it with countless peripherals before. And yet when I configure PuTTY to the right baud rate, stop bits, etc. I'll type in "*IDN?", press enter, and the unit won't reply. After going over my settings over and over again, I decided to try another terminal program, Termite. This time it worked like a charm. What puzzles me, and what I'm trying to figure out by posting this question, is why Termite would work when PuTTY did not despite the fact that **they both have the same settings**.

PuTTY:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Termite:
http://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm

EDIT: I now tried Tera Term as well, and it works. So PuTTY is the odd one out.

Answer (score 5):

Had similar problem,

I had to check in the settings under Terminal => local echo , force On

A bit too late but hopefully will help  someone else.